# ¿Como retroceder una sola vez a un fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo una lista el cual al dar clic en un item me muestra el detalle en un fragment, y tengo un botón que me permite agregar registros, ambos cargan en el mismo contenedor, el problema se genera cuando empiezo a abrir varios items y a la vez abro el fragment para agregar registros.

Cuando retrocedo todo funciona bien, pero quisiera volver solo a la ultima pila del fragment que he  ínter-actuado , por que mis datos se sobreponen, les dejo mi código e imagen de como queda.

> Código

```
//Usado al mostrar un detallle
FragDetalle fragDetalle = new FragDetalle();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fl_contenedor_lateral, fragDetalle);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();

//Usado en el botón nuevo
FragNuevo fragNuevo = new FragNuevo();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fl_contenedor_lateral, fragNuevo);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

> Imagen

[image: Datos sobrepuestos]

El problema solo se genera si ínteractuó con los dos fragments, por eso solo quisiera volver a la ultima pila del `addToBackStack()`, y eliminar el resto para que no me muestre los datos sobrepuestos o en todo caso si hay otra solución seria genial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder lograr solucionar el problema solamente realice lo siguiente:

> Antiguo código - modificado

```
//Usado al mostrar un detallle
FragDetalle fragDetalle = new FragDetalle();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fl_contenedor_lateral, fragDetalle);
//Cambie: ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.addToBackStack(fragDetalle.getClass().getName());
ft.commit();

//Usado en el botón nuevo
FragNuevo fragNuevo = new FragNuevo();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fl_contenedor_lateral, fragNuevo);
//Cambie: ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.addToBackStack(fragNuevo .getClass().getName());
ft.commit();
```

> Nuevo código

```
//Realice una condición para que no se repita la etiqueta string que se usa en  addToBackStack 
private void abrirFragmento(Fragment nuevoFragmento) {
        Fragment contenedorFragmento = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contenedor_fragments);

        if (contenedorFragmento == null){
            agregarFragmento(nuevoFragmento);
        } else{
            if (!contenedorFragmento.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nuevoFragmento.getClass().getName())) {
                reemplazarFragmento(nuevoFragmento);
            }
        }
    }

private void agregarFragmento(Fragment nuevoFragmento) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.contenedor_fragments, nuevoFragmento);
        ft.commit();

    }
    private void reemplazarFragmento(Fragment nuevoFragmento) {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.contenedor_fragments, nuevoFragmento);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(nuevoFragmento.getClass().getName());
        ft.commit();

    }

//Uso

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (savedInstanceState == null){
     abrirFragmento(fragNuevo); //Recuerda debes cargar por primera vez la función que contenga FragmentTransaction con el método add
   }

}

abrirFragmento(fragDetalle); //Fragmento que reemplazara al primero (FragmentTransaction con el método replace).
```

> si lo pueden mejorar, seria genial.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega en los layouts:

```
android:background="?android:colorBackground"
```